# Click on a Row to show info from client, Excell type Qt table

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I made an Excel type (`QTableWidget`) window where I show all the names from clients, and every time a row it's clicked all the info about the client (first name, last name, address, etc) it's shown on several QLine Edit objects. I used the row number to know what client has been clicked and get its info from an Sqlite Database

The problem here is that I can't get anything to properly trigger when the user "clicks" a specific row, I used the `cellClicked()` signal to trigger a separate function and pass the Sql query but it dosnt work

`QObject::connect(widget_PP.Productores_Lista ,SIGNAL(cellClicked(int,int)) ,this ,SLOT(mostrar(int,int,registros)));`

I tried using a simple while inside the function where is needed and use `currentRow()`, but it doesn't work either, it hangs the program so i'm messing something big in here. Here is my code.

**heres the main idea of my code**

**Create QtableWidget --> Populated Names --> click on Customer Name -->
use Row to find Customer Name on Db --> Populate QlineEdit with Customer Data**

```
void Pantalla_Principal::Produc_Lista(){
    QSqlDatabase mData=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"); // pones el tipo de driver de la db, en este caso QMYSQL
    mData.setDatabaseName(name_db);
    mData.open();
    QSqlQuery registros;
    registros.exec("SELECT * FROM productor");
    Guardar( registros.executedQuery(), registros.lastError().text(),"Lista de Productores");
    widget_PP.Productores_Lista->clear();
    widget_PP.Productores_Lista->setColumnCount(1);
    widget_PP.Productores_Lista->setColumnWidth(0,350);
    widget_PP.Productores_Lista->setRowCount(0);
    
    while (registros.next()){
    widget_PP.Productores_Lista->setRowCount(widget_PP.Productores_Lista->rowCount() + 1);
    int filas = widget_PP.Productores_Lista->rowCount() - 1;

    QTableWidgetItem *obj0 = new QTableWidgetItem;
    obj0->setText(registros.value("Productor_Nombre").toString());
    widget_PP.Productores_Lista->setItem(filas,0,obj0);
    }
    
    while (widget_PP.Productores_Lista->rowCount() > 0){

    int fila = widget_PP.Productores_Lista->currentRow();
    registros.exec("SELECT Productor_Nombre FROM productor");
    widget_PP.Nombre_Lista_Prod->setText(registros.value(fila).toString());
    Guardar(registros.executedQuery(), registros.lastError().text(), "Productor_Nombre");
    
    registros.exec("SELECT Productor_Apellidos FROM productor");
    widget_PP.Apellidos_Lista_Prod->setText(registros.value(fila).toString());
    Guardar(registros.executedQuery(), registros.lastError().text(), "Productor_Apellidos");
    
    registros.exec("SELECT Predio FROM productor");
    widget_PP.Predio_Lista_Prod->setText(registros.value(fila).toString());
    Guardar(registros.executedQuery(), registros.lastError().text(), "Predio");

    registros.exec("SELECT Ubicacion FROM productor");
    widget_PP.Ciudad_Lista_Prod->setText(registros.value(fila).toString());
    Guardar(registros.executedQuery(), registros.lastError().text(), "Ubicacion");

    registros.exec("SELECT Productor_Num FROM productor");
    widget_PP.No_Cliente_Spin->setValue(registros.value(fila).toInt());
    Guardar(registros.executedQuery(), registros.lastError().text(), "Productor_Num");
 
    }    
 
    // QObject::connect(widget_PP.Productores_Lista ,SIGNAL(cellClicked(int,int)) ,this ,SLOT(mostrar(int,int,registros)));
    // the last connect use an slot that have the second while from the code above
    mData.close(); 
}
```

note: I did use the slot sistem from qt on the beginning, thats why i have it commented there, but i was unable to grab the data from the query. heres my code using connect, if i remove `QSqlQuery reg` it works and i can retrieve the Row and Column, but i lost access to the Db, im not sure if i have to create a second conecction to my database once inside

```
void Pantalla_Principal::mostrar(int fila,int columna, QSqlQuery reg){
    //int colum = columna; 
    fila++;
    reg.exec("SELECT Productor_Nombre FROM productor");
    widget_PP.Nombre_Lista_Prod->setText(QVariant(fila).toString());
    Guardar(reg.executedQuery(), reg.lastError().text(), "Productor_Nombre");
    reg.exec("SELECT Productor_Apellidos FROM productor");
    widget_PP.Apellidos_Lista_Prod->setText(reg.value(fila).toString());
    Guardar(reg.executedQuery(), reg.lastError().text(), "Productor_Apellidos");
    reg.exec("SELECT Predio FROM productor");
    widget_PP.Predio_Lista_Prod->setText(reg.value(fila).toString());
    Guardar(reg.executedQuery(), reg.lastError().text(), "Predio");
    reg.exec("SELECT Ubicacion FROM productor");
    widget_PP.Ciudad_Lista_Prod->setText(reg.value(fila).toString());
    Guardar(reg.executedQuery(), reg.lastError().text(), "Ubicacion");
    reg.exec("SELECT Productor_Num FROM productor");
    widget_PP.No_Cliente_Spin->setValue(reg.value(fila).toInt());
    //widget_PP.No_Cliente_Spin->setValue(fila);
    Guardar(reg.executedQuery(), reg.lastError().text(), "Productor_Num");
    
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are doing here, anyway I think you are connecting the QTableWidget signal in a wrong way. I tried this `connect( ui->tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int, int)), this, SLOT(doSomething(int, int)));  void MainWindow::doSomething(int row, int column)
{
    qDebug() << "Row " << row << " column " << column;
} ` and I can get row and column clicked

Comment: @Salvo plz check the edit, the idea is: Create QtableWidget --> Populated Names --> click on Customer Name --> use Row to find Customer Name on Db --> Populate QlineEdit with Customer Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a second connection to the DB. I would advice you to check [the addDatabase method from QSqlDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase). It says:

> Adds a database to the list of database connections using the driver type and the connection name connectionName. If there already exists a database connection called connectionName, that connection is removed.
>
> The database connection is referred to by connectionName.

And then from [QSqlQuery::QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase db)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2):

> Constructs a QSqlQuery object using the database db. If db is invalid, the application's default database will be used.

So basically this means that you need to create a database connection using addDatabase (and you have already done this in `Produc_Lista`) but you should move the definition of  QSqlDatabase mData to your header file so that it can be accesible in other function.

Then in your slot `mostrar` you should do something like this:

```
void Pantalla_Principal::mostrar(int fila, int columna){
     QSqlQuery reg(mData);
     ... //the rest of your function
}
```

If you have just one database connection you can even avoid passing the database connection to QSqlQuery because it uses the default database connection that in your case is the only one you created.

I would also advice you to switch to [the new signal slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Comment: actually your approch was waaayy better than mine, i removed all the calls to the database inside the program and leave only one conecction, then retrieve the colum/row that i needed and display on the box, my problem was trying to call the Query on my function, you help me a lot, now it works as a charm, thanks